# phoronix test suite extract results from another system

Tags: benchmarking, test-suite

i'm using phoronix test suite to benchmark various systems.
I have collected results from many systems to my pc and i want to extract results to text format and then compare them.

The option *result-file-to-text* looks to the the default path where phoronix stores the results and produces the output. The problem is that i have gathered the results to different machine than the test suite run the benchmarks and the option *result-file-to-text* can't find the results in the default directotry.

How can i extract the results to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your results to http://openbenchmarking.org/ and I think you can convert the results into a pdf format there or just copy and paste the results into a text file